# EVO 960 M.2 SSD is not visible in Gigabyte GA-990x BIOS

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I have erased everything and I mean everything on my Samsung 960 EVO M.2 SSD. Can it be made to work again?

[image: IMG:]
<sup>**Samsung 960 EVO M.2 SSD**</sup>

Comment: Would any of the close voters who voted to close this question as unclear be good enough to offer an explanation about what in particular is unclear about this question and offer an explanation about how it could be made clear enough to not deserve to be closed as unclear? Otherwise I suppose I will have to vote to reopen it if it's closed as unclear and the same close voters who voted that it was unclear the first time will vote to leave it closed because it's unclear again. If there are magic rules for not closing a question at Super User, then I'd like to know them.

Comment: Actually I’m the one who voted “Too Broad” for lack of any description of how the OP erased the drive, what they see and don’t see, and what research they have done.   The question title says “not visible in BIOS”.   This question struck one of my pet peeves — putting critical information in the title *only.*   I believe that ***all*** critical information should be in the question body, and the title should be a very brief summary, suitable for searching/indexing.   Note also that, when I saw the question, it didn’t even say “SSD” in the title or the body (or the tags). … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Is the PC bootable (does it have another drive that is working and has an OS on it)?  What does the OP see from within the OS?  Have they tried another OS (e.g., Linux live boot)?  Have they tried moving the SSD to another computer?  Have they tried ***anything?*** … … … … Since you have improved the question a little, and provided a reasonable answer, I’ve retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the SSD is securely locked into position in its slot and has not become loose or disconnected.
2. Download the driver for the Samsung 960 EVO M.2 SSD from the official Samsung website and reinstall it.

   2a. Click "Download files" under the banner picture at the top of the official Samsung - [driver download webpage](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/product/consumer/960evo/)

   2b. Download Samsung_NVM_Express_Driver_3.0.exe - [driver download link](http://org.downloadcenter.samsung.com/downloadfile/ContentsFile.aspx?CDSite=UNI_SEC&CttFileID=7036312&CDCttType=DR&ModelType=N&ModelName=MZ-V7E1T0&VPath=DR/201805/20180514160435960/Samsung_NVM_Express_Driver_3.0.exe&OriginYN=N)
3. RAID mode is disabled – The error is also reported to appear if the users have RAID mode enabled from the BIOS settings. In this scenario, the solution would be to access the BIOS settings, disable RAID and switch your drive configuration to AHCI.
4. SSD drive doesn’t have enough power to function – This issue can also be caused by a shortage of power to your SSD. This typically happens on computers using USB 3.0 to SATA adapters to make the connection. Because the SSD doesn’t have enough power to function, it will not get detected by the BIOS.
5. Test the SSD in another slot.
6. Test the SSD in another computer to check if it is defective and can be returned for a refund or replaced with another one if it's still covered by Samsung's product guarantee.